# no throws clause

Tags: java, exception

This program is correct and does compile and run. But why does method 'a' not have a throws declaration?

```
class Exception1 {
      public void a() 
        {
            int array[] = new int[5];
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Try");
                array[10]=1;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               System.out.println("Exception");

                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                System.out.println("Finally");
                return;
            }
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Exception1 e1 = new Exception1();

            try {
                e1.a();
            } 
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Catch");
            }
            System.out.println("End of main");
        }
}
```

Comment: Note that having a `return` in a `finally` block is a **very bad idea**. It hides **all** exceptions from the `try` and `catch` blocks!

Comment: Really, Joachim got a point here. run: try { return 5;} catch(Exception ex) { return 6;} finally {return 7;} to have some fun :)

Comment: Interresting question I think, because even experimenced guy failed to see the real reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `return` in the `finally` block:

Since the `finally` will *always* be executed and it will *always* complete abruptly (either with an unchecked exception or with a `return`), there is no way that the `throw e` in the `catch`-block (or any unchecked exception in the `try` block) could ever be propagated downwards on the call stack.

If you remove the `return`, then you'll notice that the compiler will not accept the code, stating that `Exception` is not declared to be thrown on the method `a()`.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is unchecked exception which means it is neither required to be declared nor catched explicitely.

So to put it simple. In java you have checked and unchecked exceptions (and Errors, lets leave them for now). Checked one extends `Exception` and must be declared if thrown and handled if the code possibly throws them.

On the other hand unchecked exception extends `RuntimeException` and it is not necessary to declare them and you are not required to handle them. `NullPointerException` as an example. If you are required to handle them, you will need a lot of try catches since NPE can possibly happen on nearly any line of code.

Comment: This isn't the problem here: there's a `throw e` in the `catch` block and `e` is declared as `Exception`. This *should* mean that `a()` must be declared as `throws Excpetion`. Read my answer for why that's not the case.

Comment: Man (if you read it) Joachim got it right. Voted for him, dunno what more to do :)